# Can't get Passport.js redirect and flash message to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm a beginner with all things Node and trying to configure a simple `passport-local` strategy for my app. I was able to create a new user in my database, but beyond that I'm having trouble getting `passport.js` to work as expected.

Here's my express app structure:

```
routes
  - api
    - events.js
    - users.js
services
  - passport.js
server.js
```

In `server.js` I'm configuring the routes individually, like `app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users')`. Just before that I'm doing the following passport setup:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('connect-flash');

require('./services/passport')(passport);

app.use(session({ secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
                  resave: true,
                  saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
```

My `passport.js` file looks like this:

```
const knex = require('../db/knex.js');
const LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const saltRounds = 12;

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {

        knex('users')
        .where({email: email}).first()
        .then(function(user) {
            if (user) { return done(null, false, {message: 'User with that email already exists!'}) }
            else {
                bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
                    var newUser = new Object();
                    newUser.username = req.body.username;
                    newUser.email = email;
                    newUser.password = hash;

                    knex('users')
                        .insert(newUser)
                        .then(done(null, newUser))
                        .catch(err => { return done(err) })
                })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => { return done(err) });
    }));
};
```

And then in `users.js` I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const knex = require('../../db/knex.js');
const passport = require('passport');
...
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

I'll eventually want to make `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect` different from each other, of course, but for now I just want to understand how to make them work. As I mentioned, this code successfully inserted a user into the database. But when I try to create another account with the same credentials, nothing happens. The behavior I'd expect is to see the message `"User with that email already exists!"` and be redirected to my homepage.

Note that my homepage is at `http://localhost:3000`, so I'm not sure if setting the redirect to `'/'` points there or to the current page. The current page is `http://localhost:3000/auth`, which contains a React component with my signup form, making a POST call to `/api/users/signup/`. So it's conceivable that `'/'` would actually look for `http://localhost:3000/api/users/signup` which as of now doesn't have a GET method. But I'm not getting a `404` or anything; nothing happens, and there's no error. Any advice greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I just confirmed that removing both redirects causes a `401` response as expected. Also, setting the `failureRedirect` to `/events` produces a `404`, which is odd because `http://localhost:3000/events` is definitely configured.

**EDIT**
I realized it might help to show how I'm making the API call on the client side. Pressing a submit button calls the following `signup` function:

```
signup(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/api/users/signup', {
            username: this.state.username,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your express backend just used as a data API? Because if it is then I'm not sure if the PassportJS redirection would work.

I remember using it in a completely server side rendered app, where the routing was completely on backend, that kind of situation makes it work because any routing is handled on backend and it renders the page then sends it to client.

On a react app, the routing (the actual change in page/url) is handled on frontend, so doing it in Passport like this won't work. I think the best you can do is have error handling in passport that sends some kind of status or message to frontend and then handle it on frontend because that's where the routing is.

Comment: Oh, that actually makes perfect sense. Any idea why the flash message doesn't work?

Comment: Since your frontend and backend are not coupled tightly, I don't think it would directly work this way. What you can do is in these cases send a "messages" field in the JSON response and read it in your React application and then handle it there by showing it for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

For those still facing an issue with sessions resetting when using Passport, I spent hours tracing and debugging only to find out that Passport's `authenticate()` resets the **entire** request session internally without so much as a warning. The documentation is just awful, but anyway...

The culprit is the `SessionManager` part of the framework, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/sessionmanager.js#L28)

```js
// this line below
req.session.regenerate(function(err) { ... });
```

Passing the option `keepSessionInfo: true` to `passport.authenticate` will preserve the session, i.e:

```js
passport.authenticate('my-strategy', {
      ... ,
      keepSessionInfo: true
})(req, res, next);
```